# Showing that the eigenvectors (when eigenvalue is 1) can be chosen to be integer valued

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose $A$ is an $d \times d$ matrix with integer entries.

If there exists $\underline{n} \neq 0 \in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $(A^T)^k \underline{n}= \underline{n}$.

How can you show/justify that you can choose $\underline{n}\in \mathbb{Z}^d$?

Comment: If you consider $A\in \mathbb{Q}^{d\times d}$, does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a rational matrix with rational eigenvalues, then it is not too hard to see that the eigenvectors can be chosen to be rational. (Just get $A-\lambda I$ to reduced echelon form and then take all free variables to be rational.) Now if $v$ is a rational vector, what's an integer vector which is a scalar multiple of $v$?

Comment: (Just get A−λI to reduced echelon form and then take all free variables to be rational.) Could you elaborate on this please?

Comment: Say you have an eigenvalue $\lambda$ and you want to find the corresponding eigenvector $x$. You could do this by applying Gaussian elimination to the system $(A-\lambda I)x=0$. When you do this, you get one or more free variables (the number is the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda$). If you take these free variables to be rational, then the resulting eigenvector $x$ is rational.

Comment: Er, the preceding comment was @1234 (you may not have gotten a notification for it).